# bootstrap-datepicker takes client pc time, how to set default time from server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using bootstrap-datepicker(http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/). I want to run this plugin depending on server time.
I can change default date like this:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker('update', new Date(2011, 2, 5));
```

If i do like this then how do i apply other formatings like this:

```
$(''.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    daysOfWeekDisabled: "1,2,3,4,5,6",
    calendarWeeks: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
});
```

Comment: you need to use server side script to get server time or an Ajax cal..
Which server side script you are using ?

Comment: The question is unclear. If you already have a date from the server, then just apply it using `.datepicker("setDate", ..)`. The settings would remain from the original declaration. On the other hand, if you want to declare it with a default server-date, the pass it from the server-side call, or make an ajax call.

Comment: first run the second script and then run the first script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working:
  `$('#sandbox-container .input-group.date').datepicker({
        format: "dd-mm-yyyy",
        todayBtn: "linked",
        daysOfWeekDisabled: "1,2,3,4,5,6",
        calendarWeeks: true,
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true,
    }).datepicker("setDate",new Date(< ?php echo date("Y,m,d"); ?>));`

Comment: Also it takes string into `new Date()`, it should be `datepicker("setDate",new Date("< ?php echo date("Y,m,d"); ?>"));`